# I write a code for a saving dataframe, but it works incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas, save

Group observations into a table by type (mode) and save the result dataframes, with every type in separate CSV file (there are four types: beach, boat, charter, pier), which should produce a total of four different csv files.

```
for value in set(df['mode']):
    df[df['mode'] == value].to_csv('df_beach_'+str(value)+'.csv', index = False)
```

I understand that in the end something should turn out like this:

```
mode
beach 35.213412
boat 41.2341
charter 75.213412
pier 30.02384
name: price, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a list of `df['mode']` only unique values:

```
l = list(set(df['mode'].tolist()))
```

Then run:

```
for value in l:
    df.loc[df['mode'] == value].to_csv('df_beach_'+str(value)+'.csv', index = False)
```

or

```
for value in l:
    df1 = df.loc[df['mode']==value]
    df1.to_csv('df_beach_'+str(value)+'.csv', index = False)
```

Should give the required csv's.